# update kernel version that higher then next rhel update

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, kernel, rpm

we have rhel server with the following details

```
kernel version - 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64

more /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)
```

from dmesg we see many problems about

```
i40e: TX driver issue detected, PF reset issued
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4385541
```

so we decided to install the errata `RHSA-2020:1016` according to redhat case https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4385541

this errata will update the kernel to version - `kernel-3.10.0-1127.el7`

until now the procedure is clear

but on the next weeks we intend to update the rhel version to `7.6` from ISO installation

but this ISO will include the kernel update of - `3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64`

so  I am not sure if its ok to update by errata the kernel version that actually higher then the next kernel version that should be installed by the ISO file

I will happy to get your opinion about

some calefaction:

the reason that we want to perform kernel upgrade to RHSA-2020:1016 , is to solev the NIC network issue and this will upgrade the kernel to 3.10.0-1127

on other hand , we intend to upgrade the rhel release only to 7.6 , and that include the kernel release - 3.10.0-957

the reason that we are limited to rhel 7.6 is because from customer side , and customer not want to have higher rhel version so we are limited about this

as I explained , because we have network problem redhat recommended to install the version kernel-3.10.0-1127.el7

so we have conflicts here

but the question is - is it ok to have rhel 7.6 and with kernel of - kernel-3.10.0-1127.el7 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the KB article you linked, `kernel-3.10.0-1127.el7` is a RHEL 7.8 kernel. Upgrade to the latest RHEL 7, currently 7.9, rather than 7.6.

Freezing this minor version is causing technical debt. Most obviously, a kernel version you want that is in a later release.

Further, the support of older versions is limited. You would need to purchase extended update support to keep critical updates going. However, only extends a given minor version for a few more months; 7.2 has long since lapsed. And this particular issue might not be backported anyway.  In contrast, your support would be happy to help with keeping things functional on an updated system.

---

For reference, the upstream kernel commits in question are

```
$ git describe --contains df430b124
v3.17-rc1~106^2~260^2~11
$ git describe --contains a1df906
v5.2-rc1~133^2~57^2~9
```

Comment: so you recommended to install the version - kernel-3.10.0-1127.el7 ? in spite later we have u[upgrade to rhel 7.6

Comment: Indirectly. I recommend an upgrade to the latest RHEL 7, which will have a later kernel that includes this change. If you have a specific need for 7.6 in particular, please edit your question to add why, as it doesn't make a lot of sense to do an upgrade and already be behind on fixes.

Comment: I update the question

Comment: Customer said so is not the root cause. Why are they reluctant to take all the updates? Did some software vendor give them the impression only certain minor versions are supported? Is there a large testing effort they think they have to do again? Did you tell them RHEL 7.6 only has a few more months to live, and they have to upgrade again soon after?

Comment: I understand your direction , but for now the activity is to alignment machine to rhel 7.6 , we cant do anything about this , but I back to my first question , is it ok to be with higher kernel release then the what we have in rhel 7.6 ?